# How to understand and fix "Couldn't match type" errors?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a function (`conta :: Int -> Polinomio -> Int`) that gives me a (`conta n p`) telling me how much `n`'s I have in `p`.

```
type Polinomio = [Monomio]
type Monomio = (Float,Int)

conta :: Int -> Polinomio -> Int
conta n [] = 0
conta n ((x,y):xs) = if n == y then x else conta xs
```

> ```
> Ficha2.hs:83:37: error:
>    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Float’
>    • In the expression: x
>      In the expression: if n == y then x else conta xs
>      In an equation for ‘conta’:
>          conta n ((x, y) : xs) = if n == y then x else conta xs
>
> Ficha2.hs:83:44: error:
>    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’
>                  with actual type ‘Polinomio -> Int’
>    • Probable cause: ‘conta’ is applied to too few arguments
>      In the expression: conta xs
>      In the expression: if n == y then x else conta xs
>      In an equation for ‘conta’:
>          conta n ((x, y) : xs) = if n == y then x else conta xs
>
> Ficha2.hs:83:50: error:
>    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Monomio]’
>    • In the first argument of ‘conta’, namely ‘xs’
>      In the expression: conta xs
>      In the expression: if n == y then x else conta xs
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Two mistakes:

1. `conta xs` should be `conta n xs`. The recursive call needs the same types of arguments as the initial call.
2. The type of conta should be `Int -> Polinomio -> Float`, not `Int -> Polinomio -> Int`. This is because it returns the first part of the tuple, which is a `Float`.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the great answer of @Josepf Sible, the corrections you should do are:

```
type Polinomio = [Monomio]
type Monomio = (Float,Int)

conta :: Int -> Polinomio -> Float
conta n [] = 0
conta n ((x,y):xs) = if n == y then x else conta n xs
```

example:

```
 conta 3 [(4.4,5),(5.2,3)]
=> 5.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the error:

> ```
> Ficha2.hs:83:37: error:  
>    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Float’
>    • In the expression: x
>      In the expression: if n == y then x else conta xs
>      In an equation for ‘conta’:
>          conta n ((x, y) : xs) = if n == y then x else conta xs
> ```

There is a problem with `x` in

```
if n == y then x else conta xs
```

The problem is that `x` is of (actual type) `Float`, when in fact it should have been an `Int`. It should have been an `Int`, because you promised to return an `Int` from `conta` and `x` is the value returned by `conta`:

```
conta :: Int -> Polinomio -> Int
```

It is a `Float` because you use `((x, y) : xs)` to match against `Polinomio` and ultimately `(Float, Int)`. Therefor we know from the type of the second argument of `conta` that `x` is a `Float`.

```
type Polinomio = [Monomio]
type Monomio = (Float, Int)
conta :: Int -> Polinomio -> Int
conta n ((x, y) : xs) = ...
```